# AsyncTask with readObject()

Tags: android, android-asynctask, local-storage

util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion
 when i try to open a file in internal storage i don't know how to handle that if you have some advices help me please

My code:

```java
      protected String doInBackground(Hashtable<String,String>... params) {
       Hashtable ht=params[0];

       String json=HelperHttp.getJSONResponseFromURL(url, ht);
       System.out.println(json);

        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
              ObjectOutput out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(getCacheDir(),"")+"cacheFile.srl"));
                out.writeObject(jObj.toString() );
                out.close();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



       if(json!=null) {try {
          ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File(new File(getCacheDir(),"")+"cacheFile.srl")));
           JSONObject jsonObject;
        try {
            jsonObject = (JSONObject) in.readObject();
            JSONArray articles = jsonObject.getJSONArray("posts");

             for(int i = 0; i < articles.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject c = articles.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    AO=c.getJSONObject("post");


                    String fr_titre = AO.getString("fr_titre");
                   Log.d("hhhhhhhhhh", fr_titre);

                   lista.add(fr_titre);

        }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
           in.close(); 


         } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ObjectStreamException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    } else{
        return "Invalid Company Id";
       }

       return "SUCCESS";
      }
```

The stacktrace:

```
04-11 11:52:04.694: E/AndroidRuntime(1026): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
04-11 11:52:04.694: E/AndroidRuntime(1026): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
04-11 11:52:04.694: E/AndroidRuntime(1026):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
04-11 11:52:04.694: E/AndroidRuntime(1026):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
04-11 11:52:04.694: E/AndroidRuntime(1026):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
04-11 11:52:04.694: E/AndroidRuntime(1026):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
04-11 11:52:04.694: E/AndroidRuntime(1026):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
04-11 11:52:04.694: E/AndroidRuntime(1026):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
04-11 11:52:04.694: E/AndroidRuntime(1026):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
04-11 11:52:04.694: E/AndroidRuntime(1026): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.json.JSONObject
04-11 11:52:04.694: E/AndroidRuntime(1026):     at com.cgi.activity.ActivityListNews$GetDeptAyncTask.doInBackground(ActivityListNews.java:81)
04-11 11:52:04.694: E/AndroidRuntime(1026):     at com.cgi.activity.ActivityListNews$GetDeptAyncTask.doInBackground(ActivityListNews.java:1)
04-11 11:52:04.694: E/AndroidRuntime(1026):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
04-11 11:52:04.694: E/AndroidRuntime(1026):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
04-11 11:52:04.694: E/AndroidRuntime(1026):     ... 3 more
```

Comment: Post your full stack trace

Comment: 04-11 09:17:36.334: E/AndroidRuntime(1066): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
04-11 09:17:36.334: E/AndroidRuntime(1066): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
04-11 09:17:36.334: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
04-11 09:17:36.334: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
04-11 09:17:36.334: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)

Comment: 04-11 09:17:36.334: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):  at com.cgi.activity.ActivityListNews$GetDeptAyncTask.doInBackground(ActivityListNews.java:76)
04-11 09:17:36.334: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):  at com.cgi.activity.ActivityListNews$GetDeptAyncTask.doInBackground(ActivityListNews.java:1)
04-11 09:17:36.334: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
04-11 09:17:36.334: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
04-11 09:17:36.334: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):  ... 3 more

Comment: Post it inside your question

Comment: i can'et she told me that there are a lot of codes

Comment: Who is she eh !!!!!!!!

Comment: lol the editor text don't let me to post all the codes

Comment: help me please i'm really blocked

Comment: new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File(new File(getCacheDir(),"")+"cacheFile.srl"))); What is in this line.And  what you really want to do ?

Comment: You should edit the question and fill the stacktrace correctly. I did scrape it from your answers, but some things are missing

Comment: i want to open the file in internalstorage called cacheFile.srl and to read the JsonObject there

Comment: it's okay now ? tkhs a lot Rajesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write a String :

```
out.writeObject(jObj.toString() );
```

but you cast it to a JSONObject when you read it :

```
jsonObject = (JSONObject) in.readObject();
```

You can read it, cast it to a String and then parse it :

```
jsonObject = new JSONObject((String) in.readObject());
```

Comment: actually, now that you are reading / writing strings, you could use a DataOutputStream and use writeUTF and readUTF on it.

Comment: how can i convert this string "2013-04-02 11:26:00" to a date format plz

Comment: another question plz i have a string and want to converte it to a URL (the string already URL) just convert the object plz